# count rows in Dataframe Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to make some checks on my DF, in order to try it I'm using the following code:

```
start = '2020-12-10'
end = datetime.date.today()
country='gb'


df_ua = (spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
      .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start,end))
      #.filter(f.col('is_client')==1)
      .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
      .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
      .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1) 
      .select('ticket_id').distinct() 
      )

output = df_ua.count('ticket_id').distinct()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

I don't understand why I'm getting it, any clue?

Comment: `df_ua[df_ua["ticket_id"].count()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just doing `df_ua.count()` is enough, because you have selected distinct `ticket_id` in the lines above.

`df.count()` returns the number of rows in the dataframe. It does not take any parameters, such as column names. Also it returns an integer - you can't call `distinct` on an integer.

Comment: @darcy you only selected 1 column in the definition of `df_ua`

Comment: you're right! sorry :) .
I got the following error when I tried display(output): 
Exception: Cannot call display(<class 'int'>)

Comment: It's an integer, you can just print it like `print(output)`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

start = '2020-12-10'
end = datetime.date.today()
country = 'gb'


df_ua = (spark.table(f'nn_squad7_{country}.fact_table')
      .filter(f.col('date_key').between(start, end))
      #.filter(f.col('is_client')==1)
      .filter(f.col('source')=='tickets')
      .filter(f.col('subtype')=='trx')
      .filter(f.col('is_trx_ok') == 1) 
      .select('ticket_id').distinct() 
      )

output = df_ua.count()
```